# JavaScript redirect in functions

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I have a php page that displays a list of items, when one is clicked it returns me to the main menu a series of extras get values. These I grab using JavaScript and activate a function. This affects the `localStorage` very quickly and then I want to switch the url again but for some reason `window.location` isn't forwarding me at all. If it makes any difference, I am redirecting to the same url just taking away one of the two get values.

Here is the source:

```
//When the item is initially clicked, I have used alert to make sure there is a valid 'id'
function remo(id) {
    window.location = "http://www.example.co.uk/?s=&r=" + id;
}

//When the JS reads the URL for the get values
var rcheck = url.search("r=");
if(rcheck>=0) {var re = getUrlVars()["r"];remove(re);}

//The function getUrlVars()
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
    function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

//The remove() function called 2 statements ago as remove(re);
function remove(id) {
    localStorage['KFAch' + id] = 0;
    var url = "http://games.thanetdragons.co.uk/killingfloor/?s=";
    window.location = url;
    window.location.replace(url);
    window.location.href = url;
    $(location).attr('href', url);
}
```

As you can see I am trying extensive redirect options.

Everything works fine, it even switched the `localStorage` value correctly, except, it doesn't forward my webpage to the next URL that no longer has the `r` parameter.

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell exactly what your question is.  Are you claiming that setting `window.location` in the `remove()` function is not doing anything?  Is it changing the URL in the URL bar?  Are you aware of the possible effects of browser caching?

Comment: What in the world is with 4 lines all trying to redirect in the remove function???

Comment: Yes I am saying the redirect in the remove() function is not doing anything. There aren't actually 4 lines, they are all the redirect functions I have tried independently. They aren't all in the function.

Comment: Check your browser's error console. If your browser doesn't support `localStorage` then its erroring out before getting to the redirect code. That's probably it.

Comment: I already stated that it does actually execute the localStorage part successfully. I am using an up to date version of Firefox just to be clear.

Comment: Also I have cleared my cache several times over and still nothing. The address bar doesnt change at all. It is as if it doesnt execute the change of location.